# animation-timing-function doesn`t work

Tags: css, css-animations

I can't understand why is mine code doesn't work properly. Please tell me, why is the `animation-timing-function` with `cubic-bezier` doesn't work.

https://jsfiddle.net/r5zade69/

```
<div class="testing">

</div>

.testing {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #000077;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    left: -100px;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.78,.2,.95,.63);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.78,.2,.95,.63);
    -webkit-animation: testing-a 5s 1 1s;
    -moz-animation: testing-a 5s 1 1s;
    -ms-animation: testing-a 5s 1 1s;
    -o-animation: testing-a 5s 1 1s;
    animation: testing-a 5s 1 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes testing-a {
    0% { left:-100px; opacity: 1; visibility:visible;}
    98% { left:100%; opacity: 1; visibility:visible;}
    99% { left:100%; opacity: 0; visibility:hidden;}
    100% { left:-100px; opacity: 0; visibility:hidden;}
}
@keyframes testing-a {
    0% { left:-100px; opacity: 1; visibility:visible;}
    98% { left:100%; opacity: 1; visibility:visible;}
    99% { left:100%; opacity: 0; visibility:hidden;}
    100% { left:-100px; opacity: 0; visibility:hidden;}
}
```

Comment: the js fiddle seems to work fine. What is the problem?

Comment: it doesn't. or am I getting it wrong somehow? because if you delete the animation-timing the animation will be exact the same

Comment: it should be like slow at first and then speed up at the end, but it's not

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this ! I know what your problem is - please read my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue lies withing the hierarchy of your CSS.

You declare the timing function before the animation, and it gets overwritten.

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r5zade69/1/) - the difference is the order of the properties :)

```
animation: testing-a 5s 1 1s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.78,.2,.95,.63);
animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.78,.2,.95,.63);
```

Comment: oh, dear god! THANK YOU! :)

Answer (score 0):

Put you css code in 'style' tag in 'head' tag section. below is the example

```
 <style type="text/css">
    .testing {
        width: 100px;
        height: 30px;
        background: #000077;
        position: absolute;
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
        left: -100px;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.78,.2,.95,.63);
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.78,.2,.95,.63);
        -webkit-animation: testing-a 5s 1 1s;
        -moz-animation: testing-a 5s 1 1s;
        -ms-animation: testing-a 5s 1 1s;
        -o-animation: testing-a 5s 1 1s;
        animation: testing-a 5s 1 1s;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes testing-a {
        0% { left:-100px; opacity: 1; visibility:visible;}
        98% { left:100%; opacity: 1; visibility:visible;}
        99% { left:100%; opacity: 0; visibility:hidden;}
        100% { left:-100px; opacity: 0; visibility:hidden;}
    }
    @keyframes testing-a {
        0% { left:-100px; opacity: 1; visibility:visible;}
        98% { left:100%; opacity: 1; visibility:visible;}
        99% { left:100%; opacity: 0; visibility:hidden;}
        100% { left:-100px; opacity: 0; visibility:hidden;}
    }
</style>
```

Comment: take a look at jsfiddle first, plz.